# How do Parse the select-menu HTML? using Java

Tags: java, android

How do we parse below HTML , and get KEY - VALUE separately

```
<select id="secondary_contact_type" style="width: 150px" onblur="validateField_userContactDetails_SecContactType(this,true)" name="userContactDetails.SecContactType">
<option value="-1"> Select </option>
<option value="1">Self</option>
<option value="2">CA</option>
<option value="3">ERI</option>
<option value="4">TRP</option>
<option value="5">Others</option>
</select>
```

i used the below code,

```
Elements options=doc.select("[id=secondary_contact_type]");
                    for(Element data:options){
                        System.out.println(data.attr("value"));
                        System.out.println(data.text());
                    }
```

But it is giving only KEY , in one String value, like

```
Select Self CA ERI TRP Others
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should also select option.

Try this.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
    Elements options=doc.select("select[id=secondary_contact_type] > option");
    for(Element data:options){
        System.out.println(data.attr("value"));
        System.out.println(data.ownText());
    }
```

Comment: @sandeepgupta, you can click the check mark located at the left side of my answer to accept my answer. Also as I notice in your profile you didn't accept any answer to your questions, you will have difficulty getting answer to your next questions if you don't accept any answer.